# Truly ignore bibtex error “no \citation commands”

Tags: bibtex

I'm writing papers and I use the bibliography commands and call bibtex by default, regardless of whether I have actually cited papers or not. If there are no papers cited, bibtex complains, as we all know.

However, I'd like to use the same compilation steps for everything. So, to put it differently, I want bibtex not to complain if there are no cite commands, but simply terminate silently so that my script can continue.

I do not want to include any papers in my bibliograhy if no papers have been cited. Therefore, using `\nocite{*}` or `\nocite{xxx}` or citing a paper are **not** a solution to my problem.

Is there a way other than `|| true` in my Makefile to make bibtex not complain if there are no cite commands in my document?

Comment: rather than skip over the bibtex error, simpler (and probably quicker) to not call bibtex if there are no bibcite commands in the aux file, which the makefile can do with grep for example

Comment: Sure. But is there really no way in bibtex to just finish with zero exit status even if there are no bibcite commands? What you say is something along the following lines: `grep -qe bibcite <FP_WITHOUT_EXT>.aux && bibtex <FP_WITHOUT_EXT>`. This also has the problem that it fails if there are no bibtex commands, and if I make it exit with zero code regardless, then it succeeds even if there are bibtex errors. My solution also has that problem.

Comment: There are many tools, such as latexmk, which can determine if bibtex should be run or not.

Comment: Really? I need to switch buildtools because bibtex fails if there are no citation commands??